# Computing texture coordinates for a single tile with a texture atlas in OpenGL

Tags: c#, opengl, textures

I'm trying to use a texture atlas in a game program I'm writing in C#/OpenGl with the OpenTK library.

I loaded my texture atlas as a texture in OpenGL (dimension is 256x256) and each tile is 32x32.

To get the first tile of the atlas to display, I used this code:

```
GL.Begin(BeginMode.Quads);
GL.TexCoord2(0, 0); GL.Vertex2(0, 0);
GL.TexCoord2(0.125f, 0); GL.Vertex2((32 * zoom), 0);
GL.TexCoord2(0.125f, 0.125f); GL.Vertex2((32 * zoom), (32 * zoom));
GL.TexCoord2(0, 0.125f); GL.Vertex2(0, (32 * zoom));
GL.End();
```

0.125 was computed by dividing 1/8, 8 being the number of tiles in a row/column.

I've got no idea how to compute the second tile's coordinates this way!
I tried using 0.125 and 0.25 in place of 0 and 0.125 respectively, but this renders nothing. I'm guessing you aren't allowed to use a value greater than zero for (EDIT)the first (0) texture coordinates?

If anyone could help or provide a better way of doing this, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) in your posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get rid of the "* zoom". Just place a call to gl.scale(zoom,zoom,1) before gl.begin.
2. look through the 8x8 tiles in a nested loop like this:

   `GL.Scale(zoom*32,zoom*32,1);` 
   `GL.Begin(BeginMode.Quads);` 
   `for (int i=0; i<8; i++)` 
   `for (int j=0; j<8; j++)` 
   `{` 
   `var x = i/8.0; // texture scale` 
   `var y = j/8.0;` 
   `GL.TexCoord2(x, y); GL.Vertex2(i, j);` 
   `GL.TexCoord2(x+0.125f, y); GL.Vertex2(i+1, j);` 
   `GL.TexCoord2(x+0.125f, y+0.125f); GL.Vertex2(i+1, j+1);` 
   `GL.TexCoord2(x, y+0.125f); GL.Vertex2(i, j+1);` 
   `}` 
   `GL.End();` 
   `GL.Scale(1.0/(zoom*32),1.0/(zoom*32),1); // unzoom`

Comment: For #1, this increases performance I'm guessing? Thanks for that tip.

I was getting rather confused by the math of this, I'm just jumping back into programming after a rather long hiatus. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Sorry for the double comment, but just a question:

I noticed that when I used this code, a greyish straight line appeared at the bottom of the texture atlas. There were only 4 textures and the rest of it was transparent (32bit png).. 
Any reason for this? Thanks

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure I understand the problem. Maybe post a picture (try imgur.com).

Comment: http://imgur.com/Y1JEQ.png

The grey line isn't visible when zoom = 1 and the tiles are displayed as 32px, but if the zoom increases the line becomes visible. I checked to see if it was the atlas in Photoshop but it's not.

Comment: Hmm... Maybe something's going on with your card's texture sampling. Try adding .001f to each texcoord: texcoord2(x+.001f,y+.001f)

Answer (score 2):

Give this a shot:

```
int col = 0;
int row = 0;
float tex_w = 256;
float tex_h = 256;
float tile_w = 32;
float tile_h = 32;
float w_factor = tile_w / tex_w;
float h_factor = tile_h / tex_h;

float x_tex_beg = w_factor*(col+0);
float x_tex_end = w_factor*(col+1);
float y_tex_beg = h_factor*(row+0);
float y_tex_end = h_factor*(row+1);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This'll help quite a bit in my coordinate generation routine :)

Answer (score 0):

The texture coordinates are between 0 and 1. Imagine it as a translation of your grid of tiles but instead of each being 32x32, they are 0.125fx0.125f.
Also, 256/8 = 32. You got the number by doing 32/256.

To get the second tile (assuming you're going across horizontally) you need to shift (ie. add 0.125f) to your texture coordinates `x` values. Example:

```
GL.TexCoord2(0.125f, 0); GL.Vertex2(0, 0);
GL.TexCoord2(0.25f, 0); GL.Vertex2((32 * zoom), 0);
GL.TexCoord2(0.25f, 0.125f); GL.Vertex2((32 * zoom), (32 * zoom));
GL.TexCoord2(0.125f, 0.125f); GL.Vertex2(0, (32 * zoom));
```

Comment: ah, I got the number by doing 1/8, but same thing! :)
Aha! It's easy to get confused by the 0 here, I was completely ignoring the difference between x and y and just looking at the values as they were. 
Thanks a lot, I'll give it a try